# Am trying to get rid of extra entries on boot menu

Tags: boot

Trying to purge the entry below but response is can't find. Then I do grub update and it sees the entries. Help

```
luisc@luisc-OptiPlex-GX280:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.38-13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-2.6.38-13
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-2.6.38-13'
luisc@luisc-OptiPlex-GX280:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-13-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-31-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 10.10 (10.10) on /dev/sda11
Found Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda9
done
```

Tried the suggested command and this is what I get.

```
luisc@luisc-OptiPlex-GX280:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.38-13-generic
[sudo] password for luisc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-2.6.38-13-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-2.6.38-13-generic'
luisc@luisc-OptiPlex-GX280:~$
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `dpkg -l linux-image*` ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the full package name in the `purge` command line - you're missing the `-generic` suffix.

This should work:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.38-13-generic
```

Comment: one need not type the whole thing, just type `tab` after `linux-`, bash will prompt the remaining package name.

Comment: ... provided you have `bash-completion` installed, and the completion scripts are sourced into your shell session correctly.

Comment: ..and that's already done in a standard Ubuntu installation! :D